# MPI_Bcasts hangs on slave

Tags: c, synchronization, mpi, broadcast, mpich

I am trying to input a number on one computer and then broadcast it to all other computers using MPI.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

int myid, numprocs, processor_name_length;
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

MPI_Init (0, 0);
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Get_processor_name (processor_name, &processor_name_length);

int number = 0;
if (myid == 0) {
    printf ("Input number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
}

MPI_Bcast(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf ("Hello from process %d of %d. Number: %d [%s]\n", myid, numprocs, number, processor_name);

MPI_Finalize ();
return 0;

}
```

when I compile it and run it:

```
mpicc -o bcast bcast.c
mpiexec -hosts umaster,uslavea -n 2 ./bcast
```

It promts me for input on master machine, then it prints this message with printf after I input number and then it hangs..

Output:

```
Input number: 10
Hello from process 0 of 2. Number: 10 [umaster]
```

There should be message:

```
Hello from process 1 of 2. Number: 10 [uslavea]
```

EDIT:

If I run with this command:

```
mpiexec -hosts master -n 4 ./bcast
```

Everything works, also I have another example where I use `MPI_Send(...)` and I am getting connection refused error, however if I run that example on single computer everything works fine. I assume my configuration/cluster is not ok. Next example works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int myid, numprocs;

    MPI_Init (0, 0);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    printf ("Hello from process %d of %d.\n", myid, numprocs);
    MPI_Finalize ();
    return 0;
}
```

running it with:

```
mpiexec -hosts master,uslavea,uslaveb,uslavec -n 4 ./hello
```

I have created 4 virtual machines, generated dsa keys and I can login from each one to each one using ssh without asking for password. (from master: ssh mpiuser@uslavea for example). On all machines, user is mpiuser and password is same for each machine.

What could be the problem? I repeat running it only on master with `-n X` works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, so it's just a comment. I think that the slave hangs at `MPI_Get_processor_name(...)`, maybe because `processor_name_length` is never set.

Comment: I have removed that and same thing happens... if i remove ```MPI_Bcast(...)``` then program exits fine, otherwise it hangs.

Comment: BUt it looks perfectly fine and should be working. Maybe the machines can't see each other/can't communicate? Do other communication methods work?

Comment: @Soana, I have edited my question, so please check it...

Comment: Is your MPI implementation by any chance Open MPI?

Comment: I have downloaded from here: http://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.0.4/ so I guess answer is "No"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Problem is that I am using name for servers instead of ip addresses. Running it

```
mpiexec -hosts 192.168.100.100,192.168.100.101,192.168.100.102,192.168.100.103 -n 4 ./bcast
```

solves the problem.

Comment: You should set up an alias of your ip addresses to hostnames whenever possible. This would have helped you right now, and of course will make life as a developer much easier later on.

Comment: my /etc/hosts looks like this

```192.168.100.100 master 192.168.100.101 uslavea 192.168.100.102 uslaveb 192.168.100.103 uslavec```

each in new line

Comment: Are those entries in `/etc/hosts` on all nodes?

Comment: yes, but never mind, this was a homework, it works with IP so I'm done :D